# How to improve qrcode recognition with android mlkit (or zxing)?

Tags: android, zxing, barcode-scanner, android-camerax, google-mlkit

I have implemented a qr scanner as same as described in tutorials and that works in general. But there is a qr code (attached) that my scanner can't recognise. The Qr is correct because embedded camera app is recognising it.
I have tried a bundled variant and with gms. Also zxing can't parse that qr.
Can you give a tip how to tune my implementation?

My code

```
    private fun startCamera() {
        val cameraController = LifecycleCameraController(context)

        cameraController.setImageAnalysisAnalyzer(
            ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(context),
            QrCodeAnalyzer { value ->
                onDecode?.invoke(value)
                onDecode = null
            }
        )

        cameraController.bindToLifecycle(this)
        preview.controller = cameraController
    }
```

```
class QrCodeAnalyzer(
    private val onQrCodesDetected: (qrCode: String) -> Unit,
) : ImageAnalysis.Analyzer {

    private val options = BarcodeScannerOptions.Builder()
        .setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.FORMAT_QR_CODE)
        .build()

    private val scanner = BarcodeScanning.getClient(options)

    @ExperimentalGetImage
    override fun analyze(image: ImageProxy) {
        image.image?.let { img ->
            val inputImage = InputImage.fromMediaImage(img, image.imageInfo.rotationDegrees)

            scanner.process(inputImage)
                .addOnSuccessListener { barcodes ->
                    barcodes.firstNotNullOfOrNull { it.rawValue }?.let { onQrCodesDetected(it) }
                }
                .addOnCompleteListener {
                    image.close()
                }
        }
    }

    override fun getDefaultTargetResolution(): Size? {
        return Size(1080, 1920)
    }
}
```

[image: problem qr code]

Comment: As a test, I would make sure your image of a QR code is surrounded by the correct 'white space', i.e. for the 3 squares in squares in squares of the corners, how would a detection algorithm know when to start if just inspecting each 'QR pixel' horizontally or vertically. TLDR: make the background white.

Comment: @MorrisonChang as I mentioned the camera app recognizes this qr without  changing, I want too

Comment: @MorrisonChang yes, with the white background my scanner works, but I need to make it work with the original image

Comment: The original image doesn't comply with standards (no white / blank margin). The QR code should be readable with any device/app. For example I don't know which camera app you are using, but the default Google Pixel 6a camera app doesn't register your QR code. If you need to make it work for that particular image you'll have to look at image processing techniques by forcing white space into the image before sending to the known QR code reader libraries to improve decode chances. Good luck.

Comment: @MorrisonChang thank you, I use the default Samsung S21 camera

Comment: Thanks for reporting it. To my surprise, looks like it's related to MLKit's algorithm. My Pixel camera won't be able to detect it, nor did my CameraX test app. But my 3p barcode scanner was able to detect it. It must be that this barcode has something special in it. Do other barcode work? I would report this barcode sample to the MLKit team.